# Type-casting enum to integer and vice versa

Tags: c++, casting, enums

I have an enum

```
enum MYENUM
{
  VAL_1 = 0,
  VAL_2,
  VAL_3
};
```

and two functions that have integer and enum as parameters respectively

```
void MyIntegerFunction(int integerValue)
{
...
}

void MyEnumFUnction(MYENUM enumValue)
{
...
}
```

I have two variables

```
int intVar = 10;
MYENUM enumVar = VAL_2;
```

In which of the two cases below is it correct to do a typecasting while calling these functions and why?

```
Case#1. MyEnumFUnction(static_cast<MYENUM>(intVar));
Case#2. MyIntegerFunction(static_cast<int>(enumVar));
```

PS: No C++11

Comment: You know you could just *try* this (with and without the cast) and see what the compiler says?

Comment: Not to be rude, but my question was not whether I should cast or not. And compiler doesn't _explain_ the _why_ part (mostly).

Comment: MyEnumFUnction, you have a capital U in your name. You should fix that.

Comment: I personally found this question / answer to be useful and informative.  I think the criteria for closing as off-topic should be re-thought.

Comment: I agree @SMGreenfield

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`enum` to `int` is unambiguous cast (assuming C++ 03 where `enum` is basically an `int`), will be performed implicitly no problem. `int` to `enum` is potentially errorneous as it's a narrowing cast, not every `int` value is a valid `enum` value. That's why casting `int` to `enum` is only possible explicitly.

Same holds for C++ 11 and later standards, with the exception that C++ 11 introduced strongly typed enums and specific size enums.
Strongly typed enum is declared `enum class` instead of just `enum`, and it cannot be converted to an integer nor any other type, save for a user-defined conversion operator or function, or brute force (`static_cast`). Sized enums are declared like this: `enum Colors : char {...}`. This particular enum's values will have `char` type instead of the default `int`.

Comment: If the integer value doesn't correspond to any defined enum value, static_cast doesn't complain.

Comment: @ontherocks: that's exactly the point. `static_cast` will pass, but you will be left with invalid enum value. That's your responsibility to perform sanity check before casting.

Comment: So in other words, the reason I could get away with casting from enum to int is because of inherent sanity.