# Can we Pass Enum as argument to Long_PTR?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Can we Pass Enum to a Long_PTR?
The example is below, I am not seeing any issue with passing enum to LONG_PTR, but is that correct?

```
enum TestEnum
{
eTestAdd = 7,
eTestMinus = 8
}

TestEnum(7, eTestAdd);

TestEnum(long lEventType, LONG_PTR lEventData)
{
TestEnum eTest = (TestEnum)lEventData;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type-casting enum to integer and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762509/type-casting-enum-to-integer-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

(*The question is about `LONG_PTR` and is tagged `MFC` so the following will refer to Windows and VC++ specifically. For converting between enums and integer types in general, see the link in the first comment under the original post.*)

In VC++ `TestEnum` will be `int` sized by default, while `LONG_PTR` is an integer type sized to match the size of a pointer, meaning `4` bytes in 32b builds and `8` bytes in 64b builds. Because of that:

- conversion from `TypeEnum` to `LONG_PTR` is always safe;
- conversion from `LONG_PTR` to `TypeEnum` is safe in 32b builds, but potentially truncating in 64b.

For example:

```
    LONG_PTR lp1 = MAXSSIZE_T;
    TestEnum te = (TestEnum)lp1;
    LONG_PTR lp2 = te;

    std::cout << lp1 << ((lp2 == lp1) ? " == " : " != ") << lp2 << std::endl;
```

In a 32b compile the output is:

```
    2147483647 == 2147483647
```

But in a 64b compile:

```
    9223372036854775807 != -1
```

To make the reverse conversion from `LONG_PTR` to `TestEnum` safe, too, `TestEnum` could explicitly declare `LONG_PTR` as its underlying type i.e. `enum TestEnum : LONG_PTR`.

Comment: Note: Roundtripping (`enum` -> `LONG_PTR` -> `enum`) is always safe, regardless of the target architecture.